# Saving Values in LocalStorage onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

Trying to save this value to localstorage everytime the user clicks either up or down???

```
<script>
   var Clicks = 800;
   function UpClick() {
      Clicks = Clicks + 25;
      document.getElementById('CountedClicks').innerHTML = Clicks + '';
      if (Clicks > 950) {
         Clicks = 950;
      }
   }
   function DownClick() {
      Clicks = Clicks - 25;
      document.getElementById('CountedClicks').innerHTML = Clicks + '';
      if (Clicks <= 0) {
        Clicks = 25;
      }
   }
</script>

<span id="CountedClicks">800</span>
  <input type="image" src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/2332/super_m/64/navigation_up_button.png" name="1462_EXPOSURE_TI_UP" value="1462_EXPOSURE_TI_UP_BUTTON_WAS_CLICKED" onclick="UpClick()" />

  <input type="image" src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/2332/super_mono/64/navigation_down_button.png" name="1462_EXPOSURE_TI_DOWN" value="" onclick="DownClick()" />
```

Made it into a jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/JRxcr/6/

Can't seem to get the hang of getItem or setItem, have read hours of material just not getting it hopefully someone can help

thanks...

Comment: where you are saving the value to localStorage ? I don't see any localstorage object here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the ones I came up with when I did some experiments.

window.localStorage.setItem('clicks', 20);

window.localStorage.getItem('clicks');

so everything would be something like...

```
<script>
    var Clicks = 800;
function UpClick() {
    Clicks = Clicks + 25;
    document.getElementById('CountedClicks').innerHTML = Clicks + '';
    document
    if (Clicks > 950) {
        Clicks = 950;
    }
}
function DownClick() {
    Clicks = Clicks - 25;
    document.getElementById('CountedClicks').innerHTML = Clicks + '';
    if (Clicks <= 0) {
        Clicks = 25;
    }
}

function SaveClicks(){
    window.localStorage.setItem('clicks',Clicks);
}

function GetClicks(){
    return window.localStorage.getItem('clicks');
}

</script>

<span id="CountedClicks">800</span>
<input type=
      "image" src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/2332/super_mono/64/navigation_up_button.png" name="1462_EXPOSURE_TI_UP" value=
      "1462_EXPOSURE_TI_UP_BUTTON_WAS_CLICKED" onclick="UpClick();SaveClicks();" />

<input type="image" src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/2332/super_mono/64/navigation_down_button.png" name="1462_EXPOSURE_TI_DOWN" value="" onclick="DownClick();SaveClicks();" />
```

Comment: yea this is more along the lines of what i read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage). Also there are no references thrown yet, so heres some readin mats.

Comment: Thanks that was a big help and thanks for the added materials. I get what the various instances are I just do not have enough javascript experience to decide what goes where, bit of trial and error on my part as I am self taught.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <script>

        function UpClick() {
            var count = JSON.parse( localStorage.count )
            Clicks = count + 25;
            document.getElementById('CountedClicks').innerHTML = Clicks;
            if (Clicks > 950) {
                Clicks = 950;
            }
            localStorage.count = JSON.stringify( Clicks );
        }
        function DownClick() {
            var count = JSON.parse( localStorage.count )
            Clicks = Clicks - 25;
            document.getElementById('CountedClicks').innerHTML = Clicks;
            if (Clicks <= 0) {
                Clicks = 25;
            }
            localStorage.count = JSON.stringify( Clicks );
        }

        </script>

        <span id="CountedClicks">800</span>
        <input type=
              "image" src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/2332/super_mono/64/navigation_up_button.png" name="1462_EXPOSURE_TI_UP" value=
              "1462_EXPOSURE_TI_UP_BUTTON_WAS_CLICKED" onclick="UpClick()" />

        <input type="image" src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/2332/super_mono/64/navigation_down_button.png" name="1462_EXPOSURE_TI_DOWN" value="" onclick="DownClick()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick one:

`localStorage['StoredClicks'] = Clicks`

This will save your existing `Clicks` variable into `localStorage`, under a key named `StoredClicks`.

Then, to read this value back, you can have something like this:

`var Clicks = localStorage['StoredClicks']`

..hope this helps!

**EDIT:** As noted by Kopax Jack Herrauer, `localStorage` serializes all data into a String, so when reading back an integer value, you should make sure to parse it as an integer. My 'reading back' example from above should be:
`var Clicks = parseInt(localStorage['StoredClicks'], 10)`

Comment: You forgot to say, you have to be careful cause localstorage store data has a string, if Clicks is an int,  you have to JSON.parse your localStorage, or eventually but I dont recommand it because it's not the correct way, parseInt( localStorage.Clicks,10 )

Comment: @KopaxJackHerrauer just asking why parseInt is not correct o.o?

Comment: most of the time you'll store objects. Anyway, in all case, using JSON.parse on localStorage will work, it's just a good practice. parseInt assume you have an int and you're storage is more restrictive.,